# collapsing toolbar layout android title ellipsizes

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, ellipsis, androiddesignsupport

I'm using android design support library 25.0.1, there is one issue with the title in the collapsing toolbar layout, my title is long and it is ellipsized in expanded condition even when there is space for it to show.

Is there any solution by which we can show title with ellipsize off in the expanded mode . .

[although there is some space availbale the title is ellispsized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJMud.jpg)

collapsing toolbar code :

```
<net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/white"
            app:titleEnabled="true"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="75dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: Add the code for the layout and associated files.

Comment: @blizzard added the code snippet, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar this library to solve my problem, it works great except for shadow in title

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Marquee-able Toolbar, This code may help you

```
public class MarqueeToolbar extends Toolbar {

    TextView title;

    public MarqueeToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MarqueeToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MarqueeToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        if (!reflected) {
            reflected = reflectTitle();
        }
        super.setTitle(title);
        selectTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(int resId) {
        if (!reflected) {
            reflected = reflectTitle();
        }
        super.setTitle(resId);
        selectTitle();
    }

    boolean reflected = false;
    private boolean reflectTitle() {
        try {
            Field field = Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            title = (TextView) field.get(this);
            title.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            title.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void selectTitle() {
        if (title != null)
            title.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: can we have some modification in the existing library so that we dont need to introduce one more view . ?